# Which one is faster between map, collect, select and pluck?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have been using different methods to get specific fields from active record, But which one is faster and preferred to use and how are they different from one another?

```
User.all.collect(&:name)
User.all.pluck(:name)
User.all.select(:name)
User.all.map(&:name)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: When you measured that, what results did you get? Also, not all of these methods get you an array of that specific field.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the run time was same 0.1ms and select gave the result in this format `[#<User id: nil, name: "Tom">, #<User id: nil, name: "Jerry">]` rest of them  gave in this format `["Tom", "Jerry"]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usage of any of these methods requires different use cases:

Both `select` and `pluck` make `SQL's SELECT` of specified columns (`SELECT  "users"."name" FROM "users"`). Hence, if you don't have `users` already fetched and not going to, these methods will be more performant than `map/collect`.

The difference between `select` and `pluck`:

- Performance: negligible when using on a reasonable number of records
- Usage: `select` returns the list of models with the column specified, `pluck` returns the list of values of the column specified. Thus, again, the choice depends on the use case.

`collect/map` methods are actually aliases, so there's no difference between them. But to iterate over models they fetch the whole model (not the specific column), they make `SELECT "users".* FROM "users"` request, convert the relation to an array and map over it.

This might be useful, when the relation has already been fetched. If so, it won't make additional requests, what may end up more performant than using `pluck` or `select`. But, again, must be measured for a specific use case.

Comment: "Performance: negligible" - the query is the same, indeed. But instantiating thousands of AR objects is far from free. All of these need to measured in the OP's environment. We can only wave hands and make wild guesses here :)

Comment: @Igor thanks for the reply. Those are really good information you provided.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, the diff in performance between `select` and  `pluck` will be the more noticeable the greater the number of records. I just wanted to point out that the choice depends on the current state. Sometimes it's allowable to choose a particular method in order to improve readability, even if we lose the milliseconds in performance :)

Answer (score 7):

`pluck`: retrieve just names from users, put them in an array as strings (in this case) and give it to you.

`select`: retrieve all the users from db with just the 'name' column and returns a relation.

`collect`/`map` (alias): retrieve all the users from db with all columns, put them in an array of `User` objects with all the fields, then transform every object in just the name and give this names array to you.

I put this in order of performance to me.

EDIT after some years: now `pluck` is even present as a method for enumerable, not only for active record relations and it works in the same way as map

Comment: If, by your description, pluck and select do the same thing, why is pluck faster?

Comment: Nope, pluck doesn't make User objects, it returns an array of strings in this case

Comment: Yes, and it also doesn't retrieve user records from database. Just their names. Big difference.

Comment: Well ok, you retrieve names but from users. This is just terminology to me.

Comment: What matters is that user objects are not created with `pluck`

Comment: Yes, and your wording kinda contradicts that. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: This is better now 

Comment: Oh and _actually_, contrary to all other methods, `select` doesn't return any arrays. It returns a relation. No query is made until you try to iterate the relation. So this one is the fastest :)

Comment: Sergio if you want to improve my answer, you are free :) I'm at lunch xD

Comment: Bon appetit :) Nah, I'm just nitpicking out of boredom :)